# Error involving "else if" and missing operands

Tags: javascript

I am making a choose you own adventure style game in JavaScript, and in this section:

```
evade = prompt("Go out of your way to avoid them, just in case? (y/n)");
if(evade = "y");
{
  alert("Even though you went well out of your way and changed course multiple times,the two men are still with you.");        
  alert("Your stalkers have kept the same pace and distance the entire time but do not  seem to be interested in confrontation.");
 }
else if(evade = "n"); {
  alert("the two men have caught up with you.");
  alert("as you turn the corner, they sweep you off your feet and stab you");
  alert("you are dead");
}
```

i get the error "missing operand" on line 9 (**else if(evade = "n"); {**) and i cant figure it out. Please help!

Comment: Use `==` in your comparisons. `=` is just an assignment. And then don't put a `;` after your `if` and `else if`

Comment: @ced-b - you should make that an answer and have the OP accept it before someone else does :)

Comment: you get this kind of problems only in this section of the game?

Comment: its still in a very early section and that is a good chunk of the code so, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `==` in your comparisons. `=` is just an assignment.

And then don't put a `;` after your `if` and `else if`.